# Should we [gather] the strength to burninate this tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [gather](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gather) tag currently has 21 questions (and 0 followers) that cover a wide range of topics, from the [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gather/info) it is supposed to cover the Tidyr gather package, but it hasn't been used exclusively for that reason because of its ambiguity. There is also currently no tag guidance, which probably doesn't help.

Should it be burninated/retagged/disambiguated?

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

   There are currently 21 questions in the [gather](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gather) tag, and they range across the following topics at least:

   - [tidyr gather function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/0.8.1/topics/gather)
   - [tensorflow gather](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather)
   - [mpi gather](http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-scatter-gather-and-allgather/)
   - [twilio gather](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180068-Troubleshooting-issues-with-Gather-)
   - general "gathering" of information?
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   The Tidyr gather package is on topic, but the tag hasn't been used for that only.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   In its current state, no.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   No.

   - Twilio's gather "collects digits or transcribes speech during a call",
   - Tidyr's gather "takes multiple columns and collapses into key-value pairs, duplicating all other columns as needed".
   - Tensor's gather "Gather slices from params axis axis according to indices."
   - MPI's gather "takes elements from many processes and gathers them to one single process"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No need to follow the full process here. It's clearly useless, and there's not many questions.

I've removed the tag from all on-topic questions. There's only [one open question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51622648/automatically-completing-a-fixed-column-from-a-table) remaining with the tag which, in my opinion, should be closed.

I didn't see any value in creating new tags this time. We don't need a separate tag for every method of every library.